# Plot multiple paths in rviz

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-melodic, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to plot different paths at rviz

I'm using the following code to get a first approach (based on this repository: https://github.com/HaoQChen/show_trajectory/tree/master/src)

```
import rospy
import math
import numpy as np
from geometry_msgs.msg import PoseStamped
from nav_msgs.msg import Path, Odometry
from std_msgs.msg import Empty

class ProjectElement(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.path_pub = rospy.Publisher('~path', Path, latch=True, queue_size=10)
        self.circle_sub = rospy.Subscriber('~circle', Empty, self.circle_cb, queue_size=10)
        self.line_sub = rospy.Subscriber('~line', Empty, self.line_cb, queue_size=10)
        self.project_sub = rospy.Subscriber('~project', Empty, self.project_cb, queue_size=10)
        
        self.paths = []

        self.rate = rospy.Rate(50)

    def circle_cb(self, msg):
        
        path = Path()

        centre_x = 1
        centre_y = 1
        R = 0.5
        th = 0.0
        delta_th = 0.1

        while (th<2*math.pi):
            x = centre_x + R * math.sin(th)
            y = centre_y + R * math.cos(th)
            th += delta_th

            this_pose_stamped = PoseStamped()
            this_pose_stamped.pose.position.x = x
            this_pose_stamped.pose.position.y = y

            this_pose_stamped.header.stamp = rospy.get_rostime()
            this_pose_stamped.header.frame_id = "/my_cs"

            path.poses.append(this_pose_stamped)

        path.header.frame_id = "/my_cs"
        path.header.stamp = rospy.get_rostime()
        
        self.paths.append(path)

    def line_cb(self, msg):
        
        path = Path()

        x_start = 0.0
        y_start = 0.0
        length = 2
        angle = 45 * math.pi/180
        th = 0.0
        delta_th = 0.1

        while (th<length):
            x = x_start + th * math.cos(angle)
            y = y_start + th * math.sin(angle)
            th += delta_th

            this_pose_stamped = PoseStamped()
            this_pose_stamped.pose.position.x = x
            this_pose_stamped.pose.position.y = y

            this_pose_stamped.header.stamp = rospy.get_rostime()
            this_pose_stamped.header.frame_id = "/my_cs"

            path.poses.append(this_pose_stamped)

        path.header.frame_id = "/my_cs"
        path.header.stamp = rospy.get_rostime()

        self.paths.append(path)  

    def project_cb(self, msg):

        while(True):
            for element in self.paths:
                # element.header.stamp = rospy.get_rostime()
                self.path_pub.publish(element)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    rospy.init_node('path_simulate')

    elements = ProjectElement()

    rospy.spin()
```

I can visualize the paths at rviz, but I don't know how to plot both figures at the same time in this way.

[image: line rviz]
[line rviz image](https://ibb.co/1Qp8v5d)

[image: circle rviz]
[circle rviz image](https://ibb.co/VDs2R6h)

I would like to ask if this approach is the best way to address this issue or which could be the best way.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/361072/plot-multiple-paths-in-rviz/) by [rluque](https://answers.ros.org/users/55521/rluque/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2020-09-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2022-03-04**:
Instead of a single path_pub on the `'path'` topic, you could have multiple path publishers on different topics (e.g. 'path1' & 'path2'), and an rviz Path display for each.  But MarkerArray is more flexible especially if you want to scale up to many more paths than two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This question was solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63774548/plot-multiple-paths-in-rviz/63810708#63810708

(moderator edit: duplicating the contents of the cross-post on SO here, to avoid this being a link-only answer)

> I finally solved with visualization_msgs/MarkerArray based on this question: https://answers.ros.org/question/220898/how-to-use-rviz-to-show-multiple-planing-paths/?answer=220993#post-id-220993
>
> I post the code used here in case anyone needs it
>
> ```
> import rospy
> import math
> import numpy as np
> from geometry_msgs.msg import Vector3, Point
> from std_msgs.msg import Empty
> from visualization_msgs.msg import Marker, MarkerArray
>
> class ProjectElement(object):
>     def __init__(self):
>         self.marker_pub = rospy.Publisher('~marker', MarkerArray, latch=True, queue_size=10)
>         self.circle_sub = rospy.Subscriber('~circle', Empty, self.circle_cb, queue_size=10)
>         self.line_sub = rospy.Subscriber('~line', Empty, self.line_cb, queue_size=10)
>         self.project_sub = rospy.Subscriber('~project', Empty, self.project_cb, queue_size=10)
>
>         self.marker_array = MarkerArray()
>
>     def circle_cb(self, msg):
>
>         marker = Marker()
>         marker.type = Marker.LINE_STRIP
>
>         marker.action = Marker.ADD
>         
>         marker.scale = Vector3(0.01, 0.01, 0)
>
>         marker.color.g = 1.0
>         marker.color.a = 1.0
>
>         centre_x = 1
>         centre_y = 1
>         R = 0.5
>         delta_th = 0.1
>
>         for th in np.arange(0.0, 2*math.pi+delta_th, delta_th):
>             x = centre_x + R * math.sin(th)
>             y = centre_y + R * math.cos(th)
>
>             point = Point()
>             point.x = x
>             point.y = y
>
>             marker.points.append(point)
>
>         marker.id = 0
>         marker.header.stamp = rospy.get_rostime()
>         marker.header.frame_id = "/my_cs"
>
>         self.marker_array.markers.append(marker)
>
>     def line_cb(self, msg):
>         
>         marker = Marker()
>         marker.type = Marker.LINE_STRIP
>
>         marker.action = Marker.ADD
>         
>         marker.scale = Vector3(0.01, 0.01, 0)
>
>         marker.color.g = 1.0
>         marker.color.a = 1.0
>
>         x_start = 0.0
>         y_start = 0.0
>         length = 2
>         angle = 45 * math.pi/180
>         delta_th = 0.1
>
>         for th in np.arange(0.0, length, delta_th):
>             x = x_start + th * math.cos(angle)
>             y = y_start + th * math.sin(angle)
>
>             point = Point()
>             point.x = x
>             point.y = y
>
>             marker.points.append(point)
>
>         marker.id = 1
>         marker.header.stamp = rospy.get_rostime()
>         marker.header.frame_id = "/my_cs"
>
>         self.marker_array.markers.append(marker)
>
>     def project_cb(self, msg):
>
>         self.marker_pub.publish(self.marker_array)
>
>
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>
>     rospy.init_node('markers_simulate')
>
>     elements = ProjectElement()
>
>     rospy.spin()
> ```

And the result achieved

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [rluque](https://answers.ros.org/users/55521/rluque/) with karma: 20 on 2020-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0